# MySQL Select rows where timestamp column between now and 3 minutes ago

Tags: mysql

I was looking at:

MySQL Select rows where timestamp column between now and 3 minutes ago

I have a col named time holding a time stamp: 11:06:42 PM

I would like to pull all records that are OLDER than 3 minutes using:

WHERE time >= TIME(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)

However the query always returns 0 results, even with items older then 3 minutes present in the database.

Comment: i have another question i have store the time in variable $time=9:30:44 pm need to add 3 min in than variable the result should display like this 9:33:44 pm i need code in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE time < (NOW() - interval 3 minute)
```

Comment: i have another question i have store the time in variable $time=9:30:44 pm     need to add 3 min in than variable the result should display like this 9:33:44 pm i need code in php

Comment: @RaviSrk Could you please post a new question?  This is really unrelated to this current question.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen i did not post another question because i m reached  question limit so please post the answer here

Comment: Is your `$time` variable stored in 12 hour format or 24 hour format?  If 12 hour format, this is going to be hard to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL Date_sub

```
WHERE time > Date_sub(now(), interval 3 minute)
```